# Postgres floating point math - do I need to do anything special?

Tags: postgresql, floating-point, decimal

I am new to PG and I'm wondering if I need to 'do anything' extra to properly handle floating-point math.

For example, in ruby you use `BigDecimal`, and in Elixir you use `Decimal`.

Is what I have below the best solution for PG?

```
SELECT
  COALESCE(SUM(active_service_fees.service_fee * (1::decimal - active_service_fees.withdraw_percentage_discount)), 0)
FROM active_service_fees
```

Data types:

```
service_fee integer NOT NULL
withdraw_percentage_discount numeric(3,2) DEFAULT 0.0 NOT NULL
```

Comment: You do not need the cast to decimal.

Comment: Your math has no floating point.

Comment: `withdraw_percentage_discount` is a floating point number like `0.10`. Doesn't that qualify?

Comment: `withdraw_percentage_discount` is numeric not float. Check [numeric data types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-numeric.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on what you want.

If you want **floating point numbers** you need to use the data types `real` or `double precision`, depending on your precision requirements.

These floating point numbers need a fixed space (4 or 8 bytes), are stored in binary representation and have limited precision.

If you want arbitrary precision, you can use the **binary coded decimal** type `numeric` (`decimal` is a synonym for it).

Such values are stored as decimal digits, and the amount of storage required depends on the number of digits.

The big advantage of floating point numbers is performance – floating point arithmetic is implemented in hardware in the processor, while arithmetic on binary coded decimals is implemented in PostgreSQL.

A rule of thumb would be:

- If you need values that are exact up to a certain number of decimal places (like monetary data) and you don't need to do a lot of calculations, use `decimal`.
- If you need to do number crunching and you don't need values rounded to a fixed precision, use `double precision`.

Comment: This is a very good answer, thank you. So basically floating point math errors are impossible as long as you're using `numeric`, because it just stores a few extra bits for the sign and exponent or whatever (whereas with a float it compacts it into a specific amount of space)?

Comment: Well, if you use `numeric(7,2)`, you will get plenty rounding errors, but that's what you ask for in that case. With `numeric(200,100)` you will get much better precision than with `double precision`. With floating point data types you cannot *configure* your precision.

Comment: Sorry, I am slightly confused now. So if I'm storing a percentage as `0.10` or `1.00` or `0.33` to mean 10%, 100%, 33%, and I want to make sure my calculation is accurate for `123 * (1 - percent)` where `123` is any whole integer (its the amount of money in cents), is it safe for me to use `numeric(3,2)` for the percentage data type?

Comment: Yes, that will be exact, because the result can only have two significant digits after the decimal separator.

Comment: Ok this makes perfect sense. I also forgot you just mentioned that numeric is not done on the CPU, and is 'exact', so this makes sense.